# Help with formula to calculate "earnings"?

Tags: average

I'm looking to calculate earnings on a writing platform, based on a variety of metrics. Unfortunately I suck at math, and am unable to come up with the exact, proper formula to find an average. Hopefully someone can help me understand how to calculate the average I'm trying to find.

[image]
[image]

In the following image we have several metrics, views, reads, earnings, and read ratio. And I'd like to find out how to calculate how much 1k views gives in terms of earnings. Is there any formula that can be applied anywhere to always find out what is the average (1k = how much earnings) no matter the actual numbers/statistics?
I gave two examples to show how the numbers can change, and how I really would like to find out how to calculate the average myself.

I'd really appreciate any help there. I realise this is a super simple problem, but again, like I said, I suck at math.

Comment: This information is insufficient to guess how earnings are calculated, however, one notices that views impact the earnings a lot. Can you please add what the little i beside Read Ratio says?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The read ratio is the percentage of people who read a story for more than 30 seconds. So the higher the read ratio, the higher the earnings.

What I would like to calculate, also, by the way, is how much an average of 50% read ratio gives per 1k views. I'm just really struggling to find the proper formula here, and was down to manually removing views in 100 increments.

Comment: is this some sort of calculator where you input views, reads, read ratio, or do you have only some stats?

Comment: No, these are the given stats. I just want to calculate averages. I'm just not sure how do I get to an average. On the first screenshot, 1.6k views = X amount of earnings. How do I calculate how much 1k itself is worth?
Do I have to divide the amount of views? Should I divide the earnings the same amount of times I divided the views? Basically I want to be able to determine a reference number, and make calculations based on that.